# as3 mp3 player fail to load some mp3 files

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, mp3

Like it says in Title, I am trying to make mp3 player for my website, and I have some trouble. My code looks like this (it is in test and develop stage, so, try not to focus about things in development stage)...

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.media.Sound;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.media.SoundChannel;

// First run
if (songPlaying == undefined) {
    var songPlaying = '0';
    var songPause = '0';
    var songLoadingCompleted = '1';
    var prevSongURL:Array;
    var currentSongURL:Array;
    var nextSongURL:Array;
    var soundFile:URLRequest;
    var currentSong:Sound;
    var channel:SoundChannel;
    currentSongURL = ['','',''];
    trace("Player defaults loaded.");
}

// Testing vars
nextSongURL = ['1','NEXT','http://www.balkanize.me/dll/dl5/Sasa_Kovacevic_Slucajno.mp3'];
prevSongURL = ['3','PREV','http://tm-alonso.perso.sfr.fr/Musique/NRJ%20Music%20Awards%202012/CD1/06%20-%20Pitbull%20feat.%20Chris%20Brown%20-%20International%20Love.mp3'];
//soundFile = new URLRequest(lastPlayedSongURL[2]);
//currentSong = new Sound();
//channel = new SoundChannel();
trace("Testing values loaded.");

//JS communication
//Get next next file
function getNextSong(lastPlayed:Array) {
    //NOT FINISHED
    trace("Loading next track");
    return nextSongURL;
}

//Get previous next file
function getPrevSong(lastPlayed:Array){
    //NOT FINISHED
    trace("Loading prev track");
    return prevSongURL;
}

//FUNCTIONS
function songLoadingProgress(evt:ProgressEvent):void{ 
    var loadedPct:uint = Math.round(100 * (evt.bytesLoaded / evt.bytesTotal)); 
    trace("The sound is " + loadedPct + "% loaded.");
}

function songLoadingComplete(evt:Event):void{
    trace("The sound is completely loaded.");
    songLoadingCompleted = '1';
}

function onIOError(evt:IOErrorEvent){ 
    trace("The sound could not be loaded: " + evt.text); 
}



// Player controls
function playSong(evt:MouseEvent):void {
    if (songPlaying !== '1') {
        info.text = "PLAY!";
        if (currentSongURL[2] == '') {
            currentSongURL = getNextSong(currentSongURL);
        }
        trace("Trying to play:" + currentSongURL[0] + " - " + currentSongURL[1] + " - " + currentSongURL[2]);
        if (songLoadingCompleted !== '1') {
            currentSong.close();
            currentSong = new Sound();
        }
        songLoadingCompleted = '0';
        soundFile = new URLRequest(currentSongURL[2]);
        currentSong = new Sound();
        channel = new SoundChannel();
        currentSong.load(soundFile);
        channel = currentSong.play(songPause);
        currentSong.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, songLoadingProgress);
        currentSong.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, songLoadingComplete); 
        currentSong.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onIOError);
        //channel.addEventListener(Event.SOUND_COMPLETE, onPlaybackComplete);
        songPlaying = '1';
        songPause = '0';
    }
}

function stopSong(evt:MouseEvent):void {
    if (songPlaying !== '0') {
        trace('STOP!');
        songPause = '0';
        songPlaying = '0';
        channel.stop();
        return;
    }
}

function playNext(evt:MouseEvent):void {
    if (songPlaying !== '0') {
        trace('STOP!');
        songPlaying = '0';
        channel.stop();
    }
    currentSongURL = getNextSong(currentSongURL);
    playSong(null);
}

function playPrev(evt:MouseEvent):void {
    if (songPlaying !== '0') {
        trace('STOP!');
        songPlaying = '0';
        channel.stop();
    }
    currentSongURL = getPrevSong(currentSongURL);
    playSong(null);
}



btnPrev.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,playPrev);
btnPlay.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,playSong);
// btnPause.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,pauseSong);
btnStop.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,stopSong);
btnNext.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,playNext);
```

Problem is that my web browser, as well as some other flash mp3 players can open "http://www.balkanize.me/dll/dl5/Sasa_Kovacevic_Slucajno.mp3", and my player can't. However, other file, 'http://tm-alonso.perso.sfr.fr/Musique/NRJ%20Music%20Awards%202012/CD1/06%20-%20Pitbull%20feat.%20Chris%20Brown%20-%20International%20Love.mp3', can be opened, played, replayed, whatever.

I have noticed that the file I can not open, have some different headers (it does not have content-length header). But again, I have tried with some other file that has no content-length header, and it can be opened.

I am not sure I know where I am wrong... :D Help, and thanks in advance! :)

Susan

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like this is definately a problem with your MP3 Encoding and not with your AS3 code. `.mp3` is just a wrapper for holding a file - there are many, countless, different ways to encode what is actually inside an `.mp3` file.

Some of these encoding may be friendly in Flash, some may not. You should re-export (or "squeeze") all non-working `.mp3` files with iTunes, Audacity, VLC Media Player, HandBrake, or other. I recommend `Adobe Media Encoder`.

Comment: Well, this could be possible, but, my site now has a bit more than 80.000 files, and I am loading from other sites around 1.500.000 files, and I have no control over those 1.5 mil. I am cooperating with holders of those files, but I doubt they would be happy to process all files for me...

In addition, as I mentioned, other mp3 players such as JWPlayer (Tested it!), are loading every single file, from all my sources.

Is there a better way to load a file than URLRequest or to .load()? If JW can do it, you, I, everuone else can do it too, the way to do it is real question... ;)